# Sitecore Remote Publishing Targets - One of Two Fails Silently

Tags: sitecore, publishing, target

I have configured two Remote Publishing Targets in the connection string config and web.config file and in the content tree per the Sitecore docs.

Target 1 is on the same physical machine and uses the same database server as the authoring site. Target 2 is on a different physical machine with a different database server from the authoring site. I used the Data Source configuration utility to insure that the authoring server could connect to the database server for Target 2 and validated the server name, database name, user name, and password are all correct. Connection works just fine.

I modified the security on the remote publishing targets in the content tree to allow my publishing lead to select the target for publishing. Both targets have the same security settings applied.

Publishing works to target #1 but not to target #2. The "Click here for more information" says that there were 2 updates made to both Target #1 and Target #2 so it looks on the face to be working but it really isn't.

How do I get more information about what exactly is failing so that I can get this resolved?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Sitecore logs? They will likely contain publish info. Check them on both the auth side and the slave side.

Comment: Log file for the publish below and is saying that it succeeded. 

Can I explicitly clear cache on the slave server?

ManagedPoolThread #14 16:36:15 INFO  Job started: Publish
ManagedPoolThread #19 16:36:15 INFO  Job started: Publish to 'production'
ManagedPoolThread #19 16:36:15 INFO  HtmlCacheClearer clearing HTML caches for all sites (1).
ManagedPoolThread #19 16:36:15 INFO  HtmlCacheClearer done.
ManagedPoolThread #19 16:36:15 INFO  Job ended: Publish to 'production' (units processed: 2)
ManagedPoolThread #12 16:38:30 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.TaskDatabaseAgent (units processed: )

Comment: More investigation shows that the issue is in the production (Target #2) cache. If I go caveman and manually clear the entire cache using the cache.aspx the published changes are then visible. So that begs the question of why the cache for Target #1 is cleared but Target #2 is not. 

Is this likely because they are on different machines? How does this work?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Did you add the history engine for the DB on the slave server in the `web.config`? I think that's necessary for the cache to get cleared.